# .NET Core - Set custom route URL for the controllers

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

Scenario -
Instead of controllers being routed to the

```
localhost:5555/home/menu
```

(*home ==> HomeController and menu ==> action*),

I wanted to route the APIs to something like

```
localhost:5555/abc/xyz/mnop/ert/home/menu
```

I used

```
app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/abc/xyz/mnop/ert"));
app.UseRouting();
```

But the API responds 200 on both `localhost:5555/home/menu` and `localhost:5555/abc/xyz/mnop/ert/home/menu`. **However**, it should have responded 200 on `localhost:5555/abc/xyz/mnop/ert/home/menu` and 404 on `localhost:5555/home/menu`.

Surfed and found out that there was an issue [UsePathBase does not disable root path](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2698) reported and closed without a concrete response.

I don't want to implement any custom middleware as it will impact the performance of the application. Is there any alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could rewrite a middleware like UsePathBase middleware and put some your custom logic inside it. The [usepathbase source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c094384b2d119e147a205851e7f457149c3bbfb8/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/UsePathBaseMiddleware.cs) is like below:

```
public class UsePathBaseMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly PathString _pathBase;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of <see cref="UsePathBaseMiddleware"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="next">The delegate representing the next middleware in the request pipeline.</param>
    /// <param name="pathBase">The path base to extract.</param>
    public UsePathBaseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, PathString pathBase)
    {
        if (next == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        }

        if (!pathBase.HasValue)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(pathBase)} cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        _next = next;
        _pathBase = pathBase;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the middleware.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The <see cref="HttpContext"/> for the current request.</param>
    /// <returns>A task that represents the execution of this middleware.</returns>
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_pathBase, out var matchedPath, out var remainingPath))
        {
            return InvokeCore(context, matchedPath, remainingPath);
        }
        return _next(context);
    }

    private async Task InvokeCore(HttpContext context, PathString matchedPath, PathString remainingPath)
    {
        var originalPath = context.Request.Path;
        var originalPathBase = context.Request.PathBase;
        context.Request.Path = remainingPath;
        context.Request.PathBase = originalPathBase.Add(matchedPath);

        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Request.Path = originalPath;
            context.Request.PathBase = originalPathBase;
        }
    }
}
```

And below is its [extension method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/14c39984660a8cefb09a8d77331b47ffc48d7a22/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/UsePathBaseExtensions.cs#L11):

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UsePathBase(this IApplicationBuilder app, PathString pathBase)
{
    if (app == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
    }

    // Strip trailing slashes
    pathBase = new PathString(pathBase.Value?.TrimEnd('/'));
    if (!pathBase.HasValue)
    {
        return app;
    }

    // Only use this path if there's a global router (in the 'WebApplication' case).
    if (app.Properties.TryGetValue(RerouteHelper.GlobalRouteBuilderKey, out var routeBuilder) && routeBuilder is not null)
    {
        return app.Use(next =>
        {
            var newNext = RerouteHelper.Reroute(app, routeBuilder, next);
            return new UsePathBaseMiddleware(newNext, pathBase).Invoke;
        });
    }

    return app.UseMiddleware<UsePathBaseMiddleware>(pathBase);
}
```